# Define an algebra $\Sigma$ over the set $S=\{(A,A)(A,B),(B,A),(B,A)\}$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Like the title says, I need to Define an algebra $\Sigma$ over the set $S=\{(A,A),(A,B),(B,A),(B,B)\}$

I think this is trivial, we can take $\mathscr P(S)$ as the largest algebra $\Sigma$ over $S$.

The second question is, how can I calculate $Pr(\sigma_i)$, We can take $Pr$ to be the usual probability measure.

Comment: What is $Pr$ here used for

Comment: @thedumbkid Fixed. Regards

Comment: There is no way to define a function just by knowing its domain and codomain, even if we further assume $Pr$ is a probability, or the "usual" probablity measure (whatever that means).  Based on your comment of "this is wrong and It's supposed to be 1/16", this is a homework, or at least a textbook problem, and you have left off some pertinent information.  What is the actual problem in the text?

Comment: @BrianMoehring Sorry about that. It's fixed.

Comment: You haven't resolved the issue at all.  Am I correct in thinking this is a textbook problem?

Comment: @BrianMoehring The first part: defining $\Sigma$ over $S$ is, but I want to generalize and come up with a probability space for $S$

Comment: @BrianMoehring By the way, thank you for telling me what's wrong with the question so that i can fix it. Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, yes, $\mathscr{P}(S)$ is an algebra over $S$.

Then define $Pr$ on the singleton sets of $\mathscr{P}(S)$ however you want so that they (1) are non-negative and (2) sum to $1$.  This may be done arbitrarily, as there is no "usual" probability on an arbitrary set.  The non-singleton sets are given probabilities by
$$Pr(A) = \sum_{i \in A} Pr(\{i\})$$

Comment: Thank you for that. I was under the impression that I might have to define $Pr(\{A\})$ and $Pr(\{B\})$ but those two sets are not in $\Sigma$. In general then, for an ordered pair, I just map the pair, as a whole, to some value in R fulfilling the condition listed. Right?

Comment: The fact it's an ordered pair doesn't matter at this stage, with the information you've given; however, yes, you just need to select the four of $$Pr(\{(A,A)\}),\, Pr(\{(A,B)\}),\, Pr(\{(B,A)\}),\, Pr(\{(B,B)\}),$$ from $[0,1]$ so that their sum is $1$.

Comment: Great! Thanks a bunch.